# PCA in R: different results for caret and prcomp

Tags: r, pca, caret

Can some tell my why the `preProcess` function from the `caret` packages gives a different result than the `prcomp` function?

```
library(caret)

X <- as.matrix(iris[,1:4])
X <- apply(X, 2, function(x) x - mean(x))

car <- preProcess(X,
                  method = c('pca'), 
                  thres = 1)

car$rotation
#                   PC1         PC2        PC3        PC4
# Sepal.Length  0.5210659 -0.37741762  0.7195664  0.2612863
# Sepal.Width  -0.2693474 -0.92329566 -0.2443818 -0.1235096
# Petal.Length  0.5804131 -0.02449161 -0.1421264 -0.8014492
# Petal.Width   0.5648565 -0.06694199 -0.6342727  0.5235971

p <- prcomp(X)
p$rotation
#                   PC1         PC2         PC3        PC4
# Sepal.Length  0.36138659 -0.65658877  0.58202985  0.3154872
# Sepal.Width  -0.08452251 -0.73016143 -0.59791083 -0.3197231
# Petal.Length  0.85667061  0.17337266 -0.07623608 -0.4798390
# Petal.Width   0.35828920  0.07548102 -0.54583143  0.7536574

n <- nrow(X)
cov_matrix <-  t(X)%*% X /n
e <- eigen(cov_matrix)
e$vectors
#             [,1]        [,2]        [,3]       [,4]
# [1,]  0.36138659  0.65658877 -0.58202985  0.3154872
# [2,] -0.08452251  0.73016143  0.59791083 -0.3197231
# [3,]  0.85667061 -0.17337266  0.07623608 -0.4798390
# [4,]  0.35828920 -0.07548102  0.54583143  0.7536574
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the *caret:preProcess* documentation:

> If PCA is requested but centering and scaling are not, the values will still be centered and scaled.

```
dev <- apply(X, 2, FUN="sd")
X.scaled <- t(t(X) / dev)
p <- prcomp(X.scaled)
print(p$rotation)
#                     PC1         PC2        PC3        PC4
# Sepal.Length  0.5210659 -0.37741762  0.7195664  0.2612863
# Sepal.Width  -0.2693474 -0.92329566 -0.2443818 -0.1235096
# Petal.Length  0.5804131 -0.02449161 -0.1421264 -0.8014492
# Petal.Width   0.5648565 -0.06694199 -0.6342727  0.5235971
```

Comment: Ah, i missed that. Thank you!